# React Native: FlatList is not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to make a custom component that will display options for a new choice if the first choice is not clear enough. I am using the `FlatList` component to display the data and it seems to not be displaying the data that is given as a prop.

This is the `render` function for the component

```
import { Header, List, ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
import PickerBox from "./PickerBox";

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header
          centerComponent={{
            text: "By " + this.state.newTaxon + ", did you mean...",
            style: { color: "white", fontSize: 20, textAlign: "center" }
          }}
          backgroundColor="black"
        />
        <FlatList
          data = {this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem = {({item}) => {
            <PickerBox
              title = {item.c_syn_name}
            />
          }}
          keyExtractor = {(item) => item.c_syn_name}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

This is the `PickerBox` component

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginRight: 16,
    marginTop: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    elevation: 2
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#000"
  },
  container_text: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    marginLeft: 12,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  description: {
    fontSize: 11,
    fontStyle: "italic"
  }
});

const PickerBox = (title) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.container_text}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PickerBox;
```

This is the import statement for the PickerBox in the component

```
import PickerBox from "./PickerBox"; // reside in same folder
```

The `dataSource` state comes from a JSON object that contains a layout like this in each entry.

```
"c_node_name_scientific": "Centurio",
"c_syn_name": "wrinkle-faced bat",
"i_node_id": 27644,
```

The Output in the simulator is just the header, but the expected output is the header with the list underneath.

Comment: please add styles in PickerBox

Comment: I have added the styles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, You need to make sure that if your `renderItem` method uses a fat arrow function with curly braces like you are in your example, you need to add a **return** statement like so:

```
renderItem={({item}) => { return <PickerBox title={item.c_syn_name} /> }}
```

If you don't use curly braces you can define the function like this:

```
renderItem={({item}) => <PickerBox title={item.c_syn_name} />}
```

Secondly, make sure that the data is an **array**, not an **object**.
As per the description of the FlatList's [data](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#data) prop in the react-native documentation:

> For simplicity, data is just a plain array. If you want to use something else, like an immutable list, use the underlying VirtualizedList directly.

From your question it seems as if you're wanting to loop through an array of objects similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "c_node_name_scientific": "Centurio",
    "c_syn_name": "wrinkle-faced bat",
    "i_node_id": 27644
  },
  {
    "c_node_name_scientific": "xxx",
    "c_syn_name": "xxx",
    "i_node_id": 123
  },
  //...
]
```

If this is the case, just wrap the state's `dataSource` object in an array as demonstrated above.

If you're wanting to pass in the data as an object similar to this:

```
{
  key1: {title: 'Title 1'},
  key2: {title: 'Title 2'}
  key3: {title: 'Title 3'}
}
```

you would need to do something like the following to make the data accessible to the FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  data={Object.keys(this.state.dataSource)}  // will result in ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
  renderItem={({item}) => 
    // here `item` will be the Object's key. eg: "key1"
    <PickerBox title={this.state.dataSource[item].title} />
  }
/>
```

And finally, if the Flatlist needs to update as State updates, you need to add in the prop `extraData={this.state}` to the FlatList. As per the [FlatList Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist):

> By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

Comment: For your first part, If i remove the curly braces or add a return statement in the curly braces. I will get an error with the message stating console.error:` "Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: If i ignore the curly braces i will then get the warning message of each child in the list should have a unique key prop and nothing will be rendered.

Comment: @dpatel125 remove the curly braces, and replace them with parenthesis. (<PickerBox .../>)

Comment: in terms of the key issue, look at the adding the [keyExtractor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#keyextractor) prop to the FlatList and use something like this `<FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item. i_node_id} />`

Answer (score 6):

For me, the problem was that the parent element had `flex: 1`.
Removing it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
   renderItem = {({item}) => {
            PickerBox(item.c_syn_name);
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

First ,please make sure `this.state.dataSource`is not an empty array.
If your dataSource is something like this, then this should work :

```
<FlatList 
    data={[{c_syn_name: 'a'}, {c_syn_name: 'b'}]}
    keyExtractor = {item => item.c_syn_name}
    renderItem={({item}) =><PickerBox title = {item.c_syn_name} />}
    />
```